# Index Match Offset to lookup a value and return Offset criteria

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet of 300 invoices, each exactly the same format, in A:H. Column A contains the ID that will serve as the reference value, spaced 50 cells apart. If I know the reference ID, I use this formula:

```
=OFFSET($A$302,20,7)
```

In another workbook, I have a small list of IDs and I need to match that ID in Column A, then return the value 20 rows down and 7 columns across. I tried that with VLookup, but it didn't work:

```
=VLOOKUP(L302,$A:$H,OFFSET(L302,20,7),FALSE)
```

Where `L302` is the lookup value (I did this within the same worksheet to test). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH:

```
INDEX($H:$H,MATCH(L302,$A:$A,0)+20)
```